# CURL request incomplete, suspect timeout but not sure

Tags: php, curl, timeout, cron

I am currently using CURL via a php script running as daily cron to export product data in csv format from a site's admin area.

The normal way of exporting data will be to go to the Export page in a browser, and set the configuration, then click on "export data" button. But as the number of products I am exporting is very large, and it takes more than 5-10 mins to export the data, I've decided to use php's curl function to mimic this on a daily basis via cron.

Previously, it is working fine, but recently as I increased the number of products in the store by 500+, the script fails to return the exported data. Testing it manually via clicking on the "export" button in a browser, does return the data correctly. Thus there is no "timeout" issue with running the export in a browser manually.

I've tested and by removing/decreasing the number of products (thus the time needed), the php-curl script works fine again when run from cron.

So I suspect that it has something to do with timeouts issue, specifically with the curl function in php.

I've set both CURLOPT_TIMEOUT and CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT to '0' respectively to try. 
In the php-curl script, I've also set "set_time_limit(3000)". But still it does not work, and the request will timeout, with the script failing to return with a complete set of csv data.

Any help in helping me resolve/understand this issue will be much appreciated!

Edited: Added part of the code where the curl script is calling the export function.

```
$interface = new StoreInterface(); 
echo "Start exporting at " .  date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A') . "\n";
set_time_limit(3000);
$result_html = $interface->exportProducts();
//parse $result_html to only retain the csv format
preg_match('/<pre>(.*)<\/pre>/s',$result_html[0],$output);
if(strlen($output[1])<10) {   //debugging for now
echo "Export did not happen correctly. Quit\n";
    die('Export unsuccessful');
}
file_put_contents($output_path,$output[1]);
echo "Script completed. Thank you! \n";
```

Comment: what do you mean with "the script times out"? Is there a specific error message? Do you get only partial results?

Comment: There is no specific error message. Yeap, only partial results. The script is outputting the csv data as a temp file in the server when the "export" function is called within the store script by the curl script. If it is successful, it should return the full content of the temp file to the curl script to process. 
But in the current case, the temp file's contents abruptly stops halfway and the curl script will return indicating that the data is incomplete.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following curl options to log all the curl transfer details to a log file and check for any issues.

```
$fp = fopen('./debug/transfer.log');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $fp);
```

Also I believe that the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT option doesn't support specifying a "0" value for an indefinite timeout. You need to specify the maximum timeout value here.

Comment: I will try this method and see how. Thank you.